# Orientation and almost complex structures

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, orientation, almost-complex

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold.
Define $J(M)=\{\text{smooth almost complex structures compatible with the orientation of M}\}$.

That specific definition gives me a few things to think.
How does an almost complex structure induce an orientation?
If it doesn't naturally induce a orientation how do i know it is compatible?
Are there other definitions of compatibility in that sense?

I know that $[\omega^n]$ induces a volume form and that if there exists a almost complex structure on $M$, $M$ is orientable.

Comment: The induced orientation is the one for which a basis of the form $(e_1,Je_1,\ldots, e_n,Je_n)$ is positively oriented. Equivalently, it is the orientation induced by the $\mathbb{C}$-linear structure on $T_pM$ defined by $(a+ib)\cdot X = aX +  b J  X$ (recall that every complex vector space is canonically oriented).

Comment: Thank you! That does not depend on $e_1,\dots, e_n$ I guess, Interesting! In McDuff & Salamon they don't even mention it. For Tamed and compatible structures it should be automatically fulfilled, shouldn't it?